# change directory of ftp file on server after opened by http file

Tags: http

I am trying to change the directory of existing file on ftp server if someone open that file through http server.
Like I am sending the http link for invoice to download it which is uploaded on ftp server ...now I want that if someone open the invoice link then save this file copy  in different directory with opened status.
Please help me if any one have solution for this.

Comment: What did you try? what language are you using? Share your code and explain where you got stuck. SO is not a code writing service

Comment: I dont have any code right now because I dont have any idea how to implement it .But i want to use it through http post method .

Comment: What server-side language do you plan to use?

Comment: php programming language

Comment: https://www.php.net/ftp_rename